# Quick Regex Perl not terminated

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to convert Wiki markup to HTML markup, i.e.

```
[[Image:wiki.png]]
[[Image:wiki.png|Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia.]]
```

to

```html
<img src="wiki.png" alt=""/>
<img src="wiki.png" alt="Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia."/>
```

using a line of Perl

```perl
s/\[\[Image:(\w+?\.png)\|{0,1}(.*?)\]\]/g;
print;
```

But Perl keeps throwing the error

> Substitution replacement not terminated

It works in [this RegExr test](http://regexr.com/33sk4) and changing the delimiter has not fixed the issue. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your entire Perl code?

Comment: the point is to do it entirely with a regex, the perl is simply

`while(<>){s/regex/replace;`

`print;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a regex substitution without a replacement string. It should look like

```
s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/
```

and you have only

```
s/PATTERN/
```

so Perl is telling you that the substitution isn't terminated.

This program uses your regex to do what you want

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for (<DATA>) {
  s/\[\[Image:(\w+?\.png)\|{0,1}(.*?)\]\]/<img src="$1" alt="$2"\/>/g;
  print;
}

__DATA__
[[Image:wiki.png]]
[[Image:wiki.png|Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia.]]
```

**output**

```
<img src="wiki.png" alt=""/>
<img src="wiki.png" alt="Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia."/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl is telling you that the substitution replacement is not terminated, not that "the substitution/replacement is not terminating".

The substitution operator `s` has three parts: `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS`.

Your code has `s/PATTERN/g`.

That is, you have a REPLACEMENT consisting of `g` but no terminating `/`.